# Convert String into special - splitting an NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a string like: `"mocktail, wine, beer"`

How can I convert this into: `"mocktail", "wine", "beer"`?

Comment: what is the real question? do you want to put each word between quotation marks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *string = @"mocktail, wine, beer";
//remove whitespaces
NSString *trimmedString = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

//get array of string
NSArray *array = [trimmedString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSString *trimmedString in array) {
    NSString *newString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"'%@'", trimmedString];
    [newArray addObject:newString];
}

//merge new strings
NSString *finalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [newArray objectAtIndex:0]];

for (NSInteger i = 1; i < [newArray count]; i++) {
        finalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", finalString, [newArray objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

Comment: oh... this is the most rough solution what I've ever seen for the same problem. :)

Answer (score 5):

the following gives you the desired result:

```
NSString *_inputString = @"\"mocktail, wine, beer\"";
NSLog(@"input string : %@", _inputString);
NSLog(@"output string : %@", [_inputString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@", " withString:@"\", \""]);
```

the result is:

```
input string : "mocktail, wine, beer"
output string : "mocktail", "wine", "beer"
```

Comment: The best solution ever... Its great +1

Answer (score 2):

You need to use:

```
NSArray * components = [myString componentsSeparatedByString: @", "];
```

Answer (score -1):

Without knowing spesifically about iOS or objective-c, I assume you could use a split function.

In almost any higher level programming language there is such a function.

Try:
[Objective-C split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806852/ios-string-split)

This gets you an array of Strings. You can then practically do with those what you want to do, e.g. surrounding them with single quotes and appending them back together. :D