# Strip string of comma and words after this

Tags: ios, objective-c

A typical string below 'describer' in the database looks like this

'name, year'

i.e.

'Smith, 2013'

I want to strip this by removing the comma and anything after it to be left with

'Smith'

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"describer LIKE %@", filter];
```

Comment: Only post relevant code.

Comment: This sort of question has been asked many times before — [here's a popular one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806852/ios-string-split).

Answer (score 2):

You can use either of these:

1.

```
[describer substringToIndex:[describer rangeOfString:@", "].location];
```

2.

```
[[describer componentsSeparatedByString:@", "] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Both of these solutions assume that the substring you're after doesn't contain `", "` string.

Comment: `componentsSeparatedByString:` never returns `nil`. It's safer to use also (it returns the whole string as the only element of an array if the string doesn't contain the comma).