# Remove timestamp from NSString

Tags: objective-c

I have a NSString filled with the following from my json parser.

```
"2013-08-22 00:00:00";
```

How i can i remove the timestamp from this? "00:00:00";

Thanks.

P.s i tried using the substringWithRange:NSMakeRange function.

Comment: How does this help my answer??

Comment: Does it always remain **"00:00:00"** or it changes?

Comment: @SnakeBlisken Because it tells you how to do what you want.

Comment: It always remains 00:00:00. Thanks

Comment: substringWithRange: sounds good. Show us what you tried.

Comment: newStr = [str substringToIndex:[str length]-8];

Comment: Look at the NSDate and NSDateFormatter class references.

Comment: So what happened when you tried substringWithRange??  Not as simple as substringToIndex, but it should have worked.

Comment: This more popular answer would have been better: [IOS: string split](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806852/ios-string-split/5806879#5806879)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the date format in the string will remain same, then you can split the string based on the space in between.

Code to do that is:

```
NSString *date = @"2013-08-22 00:00:00";
NSArray *split = [date componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
//split[0] => Date part
//split[1] => Time part
```

This is a quick fix.

Hope that helps!

Comment: a quick fix for the problem.