# Distinguish Keywords from string

Tags: arrays, string

I have an Array of strings :

```
ID: 12 34 56 78  class:C

SEX:M EYES:BRN HT:5-09'
```

Now , I want my o/p should be like this

```
ID: 12 34 56 78

class:C

SEX:M

EYES:BRN

HT:5-09'
```

Comment: are you having fixed length data coming from server ?

Comment: no all are of different length

Answer (score -1):

you may found the solution at link:[string split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806852/ios-string-split)

 use **objectAtIndex:** to get each string which you want

Comment: I don't know why it's vote down. if an array has those string(array). and I want to get the string: ID: 12 34 56 78. Then I just call array1 = [array onjectAtIndex:0];. And so on for another strings.